# 4-20mA to voltage breakout: part identification

Tags: diodes, identification, schematics, 4-20ma

I am trying to recreate the SEN0262 current to voltage [circuit](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DFRobot/Wiki/master/SEN0262/res/%5BSEN0262%5D(V1.0)%20Schematic.pdf) and embed it into my own board.

As you can see, the schematics looks pretty good, but I'm unable to identify the D1, D2, and D3 diodes.

Can anyone identify those parts numbers?

[image: schematic]

Comment: These are bidirectional TVS diodes

Comment: you haven't asked but R2 and R5 are probably polyfuses.

Comment: Are the TVS diodes present to protect against ESD or indirect lightning surge currents? It's a chicken or egg thing. If you don't know that answer then who will?

Comment: Jasen in my experience R2 and R5 are *huge* resistors, not polyfuses. Breaking the current loop in some plant is bad practice. However since their symbol it's different from the other resistors they could actually be.